# sed -e unknown option to `s' - Not a delimiter issue

Tags: sed, cmd, cmder

I'm using Cmder on Windows and trying to execute the following statement:

```
echo "c:\Sources\" + (echo "Modules/ASR/branches/1.9" | sed -e "s|Modules/||")
```

Whenever I issue that command I get the annoying error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'
```

But when I run the sed command on its own:

```
(echo "Modules/ASR/branches/1.9" | sed -e "s|Modules/||")
```

It magically works. Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

<sup>Editor's note: This question was originally mis-tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), whereas the symptom described implies [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).</sup>

Comment: looks like `)` is your modifier.... Inventing a non-existing syntax for your convinience isn't the way to go.

Comment: Do you not have to escape backslashes in quotes on Cmder? As it looks now all your quoting is messed up.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'll need a bit more nudging in the right direction. By your remark, I understand I'm doing something wrong, but have no idea how to go forward.

Comment: @123 Cmder doesn't have an issue with that

Comment: @WeyensL Guess it's not that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message in the question is due to windows `cmd` which splits the command with the `|` and adds closing parenthese `)` to sed command.

`cmd` equivalent for "command substitution" is `for /f` followed by command between single quotes, pipe must be escaped with `^`

```
for /f %x in ('echo "Modules/ASR/branches/1.9" ^| sed -e "s|Modules/||" ') do @echo "c:\Sources\"%~x
```

Or when used in script the percent must be doubled

```
for /f %%x in ('echo "Modules/ASR/branches/1.9" ^| sed -e "s|Modules/||" ') do @echo "c:\Sources\"%%~x
```

Otherwise expansion allows to replace pattern `%var:pat=repl%`

```
set mypath=Modules/ASR/branches/1.9
echo "c:\Sources\"%mypath:Modules/=%
```

in bash equivalent

```
echo 'c:\Sources\'"$(echo "Modules/ASR/branches/1.9" | sed -e "s|Modules/||")"
```

also to avoid to launch a new process this can be done with variable expansion `#` to remove shortest prefix.

```
mypath="Modules/ASR/branches/1.9"
echo 'c:\Sources\'"${mypath//Modules\/}"
```

Comment: @123 do you mean `echo \`echo \\`echo ok\\`\``

Comment: @123 yes as I wrote it works but for each level special characters must be escaped whereas `echo "$(echo "$(echo "ok")")"` even double quotes are nested without escaping

Comment: Yes it is far easier to nest `$()` but saying you can't nest backticks is incorrect.